# last byte received, using wireshark

Tags: tcp, wireshark

If the packets captured by wireshark is

> 28.263227 193.54.236.133   193.54.236.132 66 55555 > 19745 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2897 Win=2880 Len=0
>
> 28.263228 193.54.236.132   193.54.236.133 1514 19745 > 55555 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2897 Ack=1 Win=5760 Len=1448

What is the last byte received on the machine having IP 193.54.236.133 ? Is it 2897+1448 or 2897+1448-1 ? And why is there a PSH flag in the second packet ?

Comment: is this an exam question? ...if it is, we don't do homework/exam questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because 2897 is the sequence number of the first byte in the received segment, the sequence number of the last byte is 2897+1448-1. When this segment is acked, the ACK field will contain 2897+1448 since that is the sequence number of the next byte expected to arrive.

The PSH or push flag indicates that TCP should not buffer this data. In other words, TCP should not wait for more data before transmitting it (sender) or before handing it over to the application (receiver). As to *why* the flag is there in this case, that is a question for whoever wrote the application or protocol being used.